# Adjoining a complex number to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I would like to know if what I'm saying is correct when I state the following: suppose $z = 4 - i$ and $w = 1 - i$ are two complex numbers, and say I want to adjoin them to $\mathbb{Q}$. The first thing I do is find irreducible polynomials with rational coefficients such that $z$ is a root of the first polynomial and $w$ is the root of the second polynomial respectively.

For $z$ I used the polynomial $(x - (4-i))(x - (4+i)) = x^2 - 8x + 17$. Now, I take the quotient of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ over the ideal generated by this polynomial, and since it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$, then the quotient ring is a field. By some theorem whose name I forgot, this field
is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(4 - i)$.

So by the above construction, we can write the field $\mathbb{Q}(4 - i)$ in set notation like tihs:

$$ \mathbb{Q}(4 - i) = \{a + b(4 - i): a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$

Now, suppose I want to do the same thing for $1 - i$; i.e I want to adjoin $1 - i$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. If I do the same thing with the polynomial $q = (x - (1 - i))(x - (1 + i))$, I will end up with the definition of $\mathbb{Q}(1 - i)$ in set notation like this:

$$ \mathbb{Q}(1 - i) = \{a + b(1 - i): a, b\in\mathbb{Q}\}$$

Now, I have two questions. Are the above two constructions I did correct? Can I just use any arbitrary polynomial with $4 - i$ as a root that is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$? Also, if I am correct, am I also correct in saying that the above two fields are isomorphic? They look pretty much the same after expanding out the terms.

Thanks!

Comment: They're not only isomorphic: they're equal, and indeed equal to $\mathbf Q(\mathrm i)$.

Comment: I suspected as much, though I wasn't sure if my reasoning is correct. Is it enough to just find an isomorphism between them and conclude they're equal, or do I have to play around with the representation inside the sets?

Comment: THey're isomorphic if you make an abstract construction. They're equal if you take the adjoined elements in $\mathbf C$ (or in any algebraically closed field containing $\mathbf Q$)

Comment: Thanks Bernard. I kind of wish you posted that as an answer so I can accept it :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the adjoined elements form $\mathbf C$ (or any algebraically closed field containing $\mathbf Q$), your fields are are both *equal* (not only isomorphic) to $\mathbf Q(i)$ since, say, $\mathrm i=4-(4-\mathrm i)$.

Of course if you make an abstract construction, they're only isomorphic: $\mathbf Q[x]/(x^2-8x+17)$ vs $\mathbf Q[x]/(x^2+1)$.